# Need help making Binary search program work

Tags: c++

Anyone with more experience want to help me with my code?
It's supposed to guess a number between 1 and 100 you enter in under 7 tries, but it get's stuck in a loop when "num" get's higher than "mid"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int low = 0;
int high = 99;
int mid = low + high / 2;
int num[100];
int x = 0;
int in_num;
int tries;

int main(){
    //Counts all the number in num[] up to 100
    while(x != 100){
        num[x] = x + 1;
        x += 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 100." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> in_num;
    in_num -= 1;


    while(mid != num[in_num]){
        if(mid > num[in_num]){
            tries += 1;
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        if(mid < num[in_num]){
            tries += 1;
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        mid = low + high / 2;
        std::cout << mid << std::endl;
    }
    if(mid = num[in_num]){
        std::cout << "Yay i did it with: " << tries << " tries" << std::endl;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I appriciate the answer will check it out.

Comment: You should also validate that the input is between 1 and 100. Your code will have Undefined Behavior if the user entered a value outside this range.

Comment: Yeah haven't gotten to that yet because i rewrote the whole code for the third time just now..

Comment: I recommend debugging before changing the code. The key is single stepping looking at your variables.

Comment: What's the point of using an array? If you were to play this game with a friend, would you start with writing down all the possible numbers?

Answer (score 1):

First of all learn to use debugger it will help you lot in solving many problems of you in future. For this case I guess it is because of a little typo `low + high / 2` instead of `(low + high) / 2`. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's good to write your own binary sort from scratch to understand the way it works.

However to do it properly, follow these rules.

Firstly, only use the < (less than) operator, that's conventional. You should only have one comparison on each pass through the loop. Do not try to return early - the extra cost of the comparison isn't worth it. If follows that you can't set low to mid +1, it must be to "mid". Because division by two rounds down, low mid and high will eventually converge on the answer, or there won't be an answer and they will point at the insertion spot.